# Read output in cmd of exe file in python

Tags: python

Hi there i have got one exe file write by c++ and i open it in python with:

```
subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Users\TomCang\Desktop\mouse_detect.exe"])
```

And, I want to get the result string when run it in the window shell. I searched too much question here but i have seen only read command line output like:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('ping google.com', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Cannot use with my code. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at `subprocess.check_output` ?

Comment: you mean like result = subprocess.check_output(shell=True)

Comment: Don't use the shell argument - just use `output = subprocess.check_output([r'C:\Users\TomCang\Desktop\mouse_detect.exe'])`

Comment: It worked! Thanks alot @JonClements